Using highcharts offline-encoding and bundle it to C# .net
I am using .NET version 4.8.
Also, using high-chart (currently version 8.0.0)
I see lately as high-chart privacy disclaimer that I need to head headers:
referer and user-agent
As the claim of high-chart, I can be blocked, whenever I do too many requests for the site, so I more need to set up my own server, as the explanation at high-chart setting up the server
I see that the headers are passed correctly in my code, but nevertheless, there still an exception that the call to highchart exporting is blocked.
As I understood that I can use offline-exporting.js
I have old version of exporting.js - Highcharts JS v8.0.0 (2019-12-10)
In bundleConfig.cs, the code for including the highchat json is:
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highcharts").Include(
    "~/Scripts/highcharts.js",
    "~/Scripts/exporting.js",
    "~/Scripts/drilldown.js",
    "~/Scripts/no-data-to-display.js",
    "~/Scripts/highcharts-3d.js",
    "~/Scripts/highcharts-more.js",
    "~/Scripts/histogram-bellcurve.js"));

I just added to the list offline-exporting.js, but get an exception for the script:

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isSafari' of 't' as it is
undefined.

The new version of offline-exporting.js is: Highcharts JS v11.4.8 (2024-08-29)
I didn't find any documentation for adding this offline-exporting, and what to put in the bundle (it is a new version - v11.4.8 vs the old one v8.0.0).
Also for the exporting clause, I added: fallbackToExportServer: false
exporting: {
    fallbackToExportServer: false,
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: [
                'printChart',
                'separator',
                'downloadPNG',
                'downloadJPEG',
                'downloadPDF',
                'downloadSVG'
            ]
        }
    }
}

What can be done in order to include and implement offline-exporting.js in my code, and doing everything necessary (changing bundleConfig.cs, etc.)?
Also, any upgrade break the code, when trying rendering to new version of highchart (8.0.0 -> v11.4.8), probably of broken webgrease library, as I saw in some posts: webgreeze problem
That is since, when trying to add the new versions of *.js of highcharts:
@section scripts{
    ...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/highcharts")
}

I get:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
instance of an object.'

The source (of the exception): WebGrease.
Probably this due some versions compatibilities.
Is someone aware for that behavior?

Hi, do you use official integration Highcharts .NET Standard Wrapper ?

I don't have a nuget package of highsoft.highcharts.
as for: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Docs?section=UpgradeToStandard.
I have just the javascripts bundled into the project, as mentioned.
It is from: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/download/
I just get into the project, when there is already code for that.|
All I want to do is to enable the offline-exporting, since changes as https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/privacy-disclaimer-export

You're right, the new Fair Usage Policy suggests that limits may be imposed especially when many requests are sent to the server. If that was your use case, I would suggest either setting up your own Export Server or using the offline exporting module.
The usage of offline exporting is very simple: https://jsfiddle.net/9cheza5d/
When the module is imported, all the charts get exported without an additional request to the export server by default (BUT not always, here's a chart showing when: https://assets.highcharts.com/images/client-side-export-flow.svg)
Another things worth keeping in mind:

You need to have the same version of Highcharts, exporting.js and offline-exporting.js:

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.0/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.0/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.0/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>

You can't mix different versions - I would suggest you use 11.4.8 for all the Highcharts packages that you import. That's most likely the culprit of the isSafari issue as I can't reproduce it with either v8 or v11. If you can reproduce it in JSFiddle, please share a link and I will investigate.

Regarding webgrease, I would suggest you clear the cache and re-bundle resources -- if your config is proper, it should help.

If you have some custom JS code in regards to offline exporting, you can use the exportChartLocal method documented here and here's a demo.


